# Sort table by column value before display jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it's possible to sort the final table content, before inserting it into the html, by the value of the paying column. The code generating the table is the following

```
function populateJobMarket() {
  var tableContent = '';
  $.getJSON('modalRoutes/jobmarket', function(data){
     $.each(data, function() {
      var cName = this.companyName;
      $.each(this.hiring, function(){
        tableContent += '<tr class=\'target_row\'>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + cName + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + this.paying + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td> <button type=\'button\' class=\'btn btn-warning job_apply\' id=' + this._id + '> Apply </button></td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
      });
    });
    $('#jobMarket_pp #joblist table tbody').html(tableContent); // Sort it before this step
  });

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="jobMarket_pp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="jobMarket_pp">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="jobMarket_content" Job Offers</h4> </div> <div class="modal-body"> <div class='jobMarketAlert'></div>
                        <div id="joblist">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Company Name</th>
                                    <th>Salary</th>
                                    <th>Work</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: please insert your html code

Comment: @AleshaOleg inserted html code

Comment: @charlietfl It's not even close to that.

Comment: What's not? you really haven't provided enough detail for us to know what issue really is. We have no idea what your data structure looks like

Comment: You can tell by the TWO loops that it would look like `[{a : [{a1}, {a2}]},{b: [{b1},{b2}]} ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to flatten the data:

```
var new_data = [];

$.each(data, function() {
  var companyName = this.companyName;
  $(this.hiring).each(function(index, hire){
    hire.companyName = companyName;
    new_data.push(hire);
  });
});
```

Then sort the new flattened data by paying:

```
new_data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.paying < b.paying;
});
```

Now iterate over the data:

```
$.each($(new_data), function(){
  tableContent += '<tr class=\'target_row\'>';
  tableContent += '<td>' + this.companyName + '</td>';
  tableContent += '<td>' + this.paying + '</td>';
  tableContent += '<td> <button type=\'button\' class=\'btn btn-warning job_apply\' id=' + this._id + '> Apply </button></td>';
  tableContent += '</tr>'
});
```

I also recommend using, instead:

```
$(new_data).each(function(hire)) {
  tableContent += '<tr class=\'target_row\'>';
  tableContent += '<td>' + hire.companyName + '</td>';
  tableContent += '<td>' + hire.paying + '</td>';
  tableContent += '<td> <button type=\'button\' class=\'btn btn-warning job_apply\' id=' + hire._id + '> Apply </button></td>';
  tableContent += '</tr>'
});
```

Using `this` is JavaScript often leads to headaches, as it doesn't behave like `this` in other languages.

Comment: Paying is already sorted from the server for each `company`, the problem is not sorting the inside data is sorting all data based on paying.

Comment: You'll have to flatten "data" then, see my updated answer

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks for the `this` suggestion but JS is the first language I learned so `this` behaves the intended way :). Other than that .. brilliant solution.